# roots of $z^7 − 2z^5 + 6z^3 − z + 1 = 0$ in the disc $|z| < 1$?

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, solution-verification

The Q is How many roots does the equation $z^7 − 2z^5 + 6z^3 − z + 1 = 0$ have in the disc $|z| < 1$?

My approach : To count the roots of $f$
in the unit disk $D =\lbrace \vert z \vert < 1 \rbrace $
, let $g(z)$ be the dominant
term of $f$ on its boundary which is the unit circle,
$g(z) = 6z^3$:
Then on the unit circle we have
$\vert f(z)-g(z)\vert  = \vert z^7 − 2z^5 + 6z^3 − z + 1 -6z^3 \vert = \vert   z^7 − 2z^5  − z + 1\vert \leq 5 < 6 = \vert g(z)\vert $

Now by Rouche's Theorem  we get that in $D$ $g$ and $f$ have the same number of roots . 
As $g$ has one root in $D$ , given polynomial has $1$ root in $D$

Is this correct ?

EDIT : Should I consider with multiplicity ? Then answer would be $3$ I guess.

Comment: It has three roots.

Comment: With considering multiplicity you mean right ?

Comment: What does the theorem say?

Comment: Ok. It includes multiplicity.

Comment: [See this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%27s_theorem)

Comment: @SMath: Good job.